# how do i fix this error about POST net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

when i post ajax, error occurs.
[image]
these are my codes.

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
let data ={
      "name": "test",
      "phone": "12345678",
      "email": "test@test.com",
      "content": "i wish"
    }
let dataStr = JSON.stringify(data)
xhr.open('post',apiUrl,true) // apiUrl is provided from back side
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json')
xhr.send(dataStr)
```

it has bothered me few days,please help me.

Comment: Connection refused means that there's no webserver running at the given URL. Or there could be a firewall blocking you from connecting to it.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that the web application is not available / not running. To verify it, create a manually post request via postman or similar apps directly into the API to check the connection.

Answer (score 0):

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED is due to when code cant access the given url, it is due to various reasons

1. Firewall blocking
2. Url may be down
3. Internet issue etc

Try checking it while accessing it manually or through the postman or just put a try catch block in your code, it will give you exact status.